# Convex Hull on clusters generated by Kmeans

Tags: postgis, clustering

I am trying to use Convex Hull on the result of K-means. Here is my code:

```
with data as(
select at2."name" as area_type, a.name,bf.* from building_footprints bf
left join area a on bf."areaID" = a."ID"
left join area_type at2 on at2."ID" = a."areaTypeID"
where a."ID" in (select "areaID" from campaign_scope)
and at2."name"='Uc'
and a.name='test'
)
,
kmeans as(
select "area_type", "name",
"ID",
"geoJson" ,
ST_ClusterKMeans(st_transform(data."geoJson",24313), (select (count(*)/20)::integer from data),25 ) OVER (order by data."ID") AS cluster_id
FROM data
)


select cluster_id,ST_Buffer(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(kmeans."geoJson")),0.001) 
from kmeans
group by 1
```

Is this the correct approach? I basically want to draw a polygon around all clusters generated by K-means. This code does indeed give a result set, with circle-ish polygons around clusters, but I wanted to check if I am using the convex hull and st_collect functions correctly.

Also, how can I show the buildings (geometries) inside the Convex Hull? Currently I can only see the outline of the Convex Hull.